# ie7 conditional override is not working

Tags: css, internet-explorer-7

```
<!--[if lt IE 9]><link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/a/s/major-market/non-reponsive.css" /><![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 7]><link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/a/s/major-market/ie7.css"><![endif]-->
```

I have conditionally included this two statements. Now when I try to ovveride a similar css in ie7.css it doesnot work. for example

In non-reponsive.css:

```
.header .features{
   width:25%;
}
```

In ie7.css:

```
.header .features{
   width:20%!important;
}
```

This is not working for some reason. please help me figure it out.

Comment: Could you show us a demo that shows the problem? It's hard to tell what causes it without seeing it in action.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ensure that the `IE 7` conditional include is located below all other CSS declarations/includes within the page otherwise it will get overruled.

Comment: yeah it is at the end

Comment: actually my doubt is i checked for below ie9 and equal to ie7 does that create any issue ??

Answer (score 0):

I am quite sure ie7.css is not loaded at all. `!important` would override anything in other stylesheets. Actually, if ie7.css comes after non-responsive.css, `!important` is unnecessary anyways.

That's the most I can tell by looking at the information you have provided.